# Make ConcurrentMapCacheManager transaction aware in xml

Tags: java, spring, caching, spring-data

I have to use XML configuration combined with annotations in this app. In my config, I have defined a cache manager:

```
<cache:annotation-driven />
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheManager"/>
```

And I have several service methods that are annotated for both caching and transactions.

```
@Cacheable("userCache")
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
User getByUsername( String username );
```

and

```
@CacheEvict(value = "userCache", allEntries = true),
@Transactional
void save(List<User> users);
```

I need to make `ConcurrentMapCacheManager` transaction aware. I have seen examples such as in the article [Spring cache annotations: some tips & tricks](https://www.foreach.be/blog/spring-cache-annotations-some-tips-tricks) that shows how to wrap a cache manager in a transaction aware proxy via a `@Bean` method, but cannot work out how to do this with XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I have solved this. In my context, I declare a custom cache manager

```
<cache:annotation-driven />
<bean id="cacheManager" class="com.sample.cache.TransactionAwareCacheManager"/>
```

The custom cache manager is a transaction aware proxy, wrapping the actual cache manager.

```
package com.sample.cache;

import org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.transaction.TransactionAwareCacheManagerProxy;

public class TransactionAwareCacheManager extends TransactionAwareCacheManagerProxy {
   public TransactionAwareCacheManager() {
      super(new ConcurrentMapCacheManager());
   }
}
```